# Problem using RestFB

Tags: restfb

Can you provide solution to following question:
[How to create a java class for a JSON string where keys are variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776699/how-to-create-a-java-class-for-a-json-string-where-keys-are-variable) .
Here we are not able to collect all stats objects as key is dynamic.

Thanks,
Jayant

Answer (score 0):

I'm Mark Allen (RestFB maintainer).  Version 1.6 should address this with its support for mapping results to the new JsonObject type.  Check out http://restfb.com for an example of how to do this.